# Why is the characteristic function of the sum of R.V define in the joint space the same as the characteristic function of the sum in the sum space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Suppose I have a set of independent random variables $\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\}$ and I calculate a new variable $Y(X_1,\dots,X_n)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}X_i$. In order to calculate the characteristic function of Y, $\phi_Y(t)$, I saw in many books, that the correct procedure is the following:
\begin{equation}\phi_Y(t)=\phi_{\sum^{n}_{i=1}X_i}(t)=E[e^{i\, \sum^{n}_{j=1}X_j\,t}]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{i\, \sum^{n}_{j=1}X_j\, t}\, f_{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\,\text{d}^{n}x=\prod^{n}_{j}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{i\, X_j\, t}\, f_{X_j}(x_j)\, \text{d}x_j=\prod^{n}_{j}\phi_{X_j}(t).
\end{equation}
What I can't understand is why or even if this procedure is the same as doing this
\begin{equation}\phi_Y(t)=E[e^{i\,Y\,t}]=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{i\,y\,t}\, f_{Y}(y)\, \text{d}y.
\end{equation}
I get that you can calculate the expected value of any function of the variables where you define your probability space, for example, the variance: $Var(X)=E[(X-E(X))^{2}]$. But I can´t understand why $\phi_Y(t)=\phi_{\sum^{n}_{i=1}X_i}(t)$ is a valid step.

Comment: Are you comfortable with writing $\mathbb{E}[h(X)] = \int h(x) f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x$? If so, then the above is just doing the same with a composition of functions - if $Y = h(X)$, then $\mathbb{E}[ g(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[g(h(X)],$ and the formula arises by expanding the second expectation into an integral.

Comment: If you want to dig deeper, this is clarified by the basic structure of probability theory, wherein there is one underlying probability space, and all random variables are function from this space, and integrals are always defined as per the underlying space. Then all these equalities amount to various change of variables (much like substitution in standard Riemann integration). Consult the early chapters of any book on measure-theoretic probability (although depending on background this may be way too much).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 But if you do as you suggest, doesn`t the absolut value of the Jacobian appears multiplying the integral argument now? I mean, now the expressions are the same as the ones I wrote above, but there is an extra $\|J\|$ multiplying inside the integrals.

Comment: What is $\ w\ $ doing in your equations?  I don't believe it should be there. [By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Definition), the characteristic function of $\ Y\ $ is $\ \phi_Y(t)=E\big(e^{itY}\big)\ $ and the characteristic function of $\ X_i\ $ is $\ \phi_{X_i}(t)=E\big(e^{it{X_i}}\big)\ $. So
\begin{align}
\phi_Y(t)&=E\big(e^{itY}\big)\\
&=E\Big(e^{it\sum_\limits{j=1}^nX_j}\Big)\\
&=E\Big(\prod_{j=1}^ne^{itX_j}\Big)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^nE\big(e^{itX_j}\big)\ \ (\text{by independence})\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^n\phi_{X_i}(t)\ .
\end{align}

Comment: @JuanOctavioCastro Well the $\mathbb{E}[g(h(X))]$ is just an integral over the $X$s. If you explicitly want to write a change of variables from the $Y$ integral to the $X$ one, then the Jacobian is conveniently hidden away in the relationship between $f_Y(y)$ and $f_X(x_1,\dots, x_n)$. Indeed, you can be very explicit and work out an expression for $f_Y$ in terms of $f_X$ (which would involve some factor $J$), and then run the integral. The point of the given calculation is to avoid explicitly working out $f_Y$, thus saving work. Also, lonza's point regarding $w$ is very valid.

Comment: @lonza leggiera yes! So sorry, I was thinking in Fourier Transforms while writing the question. If I can, I will correct it.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you for the responses. I think I will get a better grip on the idea when I see that it's the same result either way. So I'm going to write explicitly the change of variables in the 2-D case.

Comment: Sure. Since you're familiar with Fourier analytic techniques, the simple thing to show is that for two independent random variables $X_1, X_2$ with densities $f_1, f_2$, the density of $Y = X_1 + X_2$ is the convolution $f_Y = f_1 * f_2$. Notice that this immediately yields the result in the question, since the characteristic function is the Fourier transform of the density.

Answer (score 1):

To see that the two expressions
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{it\sum_\limits{j=1}^nx_j}f_X(x)d^nx
$$
and
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}e^{ity}f_Y(y)dy\ ,
$$
reduce to the same thing, you shouldn't really need to do anything more than observe that both are equal to
$$
E\Bigg(e^{it\sum_\limits{j=1}^nX_j}\Bigg)=E\big(e^{itY}\big)\ .
$$
However, if you're curious to see how the second integral can be reduced to the first, you simply need to replace $\ f_Y(y)\ $ in the second integral by its expression in terms of $\ f_X\ $, which it must have, because $\ Y=\sum_\limits{j=1}^nX_j $. One equation (of several) connecting the two is
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}f_X\Big(x_1,x_2,\dots,y-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}x_j\Big)dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{n-1}\ .
$$
Substituting the expression on the right of this identity for $\ f_Y(y)\ $ in the integral $\ \int_\mathbb{R}e^{ity}f_Y(y)dy\ $ gives
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}e^{ity}f_Y(y)dy=&\int_\mathbb{R}e^{ity}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}f_X\Big(x_1,x_2,\dots,y-\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n-1}x_j\Big)dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{n-1}dy\\
=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{ity}f_X\Big(x_1,x_2,\dots,y-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}x_j\Big)dy\,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{n-1}\\
=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{it\sum_\limits{j=1}^nx_j}f_X\big(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\big)dx_ndx_1dx_2\dots dx_{n-1}\ ,
\end{align}
by changing variables in the innermost integral from $\ y\ $ to $\ x_n=y-\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n-1}x_j\ $.